# MySQL 5.5 Continuously getting crashed

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have MySQL  5.5.44 running in RHEL server. It is a standalone server used for testing and offlate not much used. The instance is currently down. Hence, I tried to start the service. It got started but everytime I check

> ps -ef | grep mysql

The process ID is getting changed and mysql instance is continuously getting restarted.

my.cnf entries:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
#log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
log-bin-trust-function-creators=1
log=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.log
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G
innodb_fast_shutdown=0
innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
port            = 3306
```

Error log entries:

```
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 580582798, file name /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000108
160709 12:21:49  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160709 12:21:50 InnoDB: 5.5.44 started; log sequence number 166058394317
160709 12:21:50 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
160709 12:21:50 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
160709 12:21:50 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
160709 12:21:50 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160709 12:21:50 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.44-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
160709 12:21:50 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
160709 12:21:50 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
160709 12:21:50 [Warning] The syntax '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--general-log'/'--general-log-file' instead.
160709 12:21:50 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.44-log) starting as process 15180 ...
160709 12:21:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160709 12:21:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160709 12:21:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160709 12:21:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160709 12:21:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 3.0G
160709 12:21:51 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160709 12:21:51 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 166055317403
160709 12:21:51  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 166058394317
160709 12:21:51  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81
```

The above log entries is getting updated as and when instance is restarted.. the instance continues to restart every 4-5 seconds.

Help required here.!

Comment: Could you show multiple "cycles" of restarts in the log? do the percents at the end get to 100? I can see no actual crash in that output so either it is in other part of the log or it is not there -> check the syslog or similar for possible out of memory error and mysqld kills.

Comment: @jkavalik The percentage keeps reaching 89 and then restarts again.. You want me to check which log?

Comment: syslog, dmesg and similar stuff, check other logs for any mentions of mysqld.. what you show here is the restart and recovery but no crash or error which would hint on a reason.

Comment: @jkavalik There aren't anything related to out of memory regarding mysqld in the kernel logs, if I start the mysqld with innodb_recovery =4, it doesn't restart.. it stays proper.. but when I remove it, it starts restarting continuously, any other ways to debug this issue?.

Comment: Take binary backup. Try to take a proper full backup with innodb recovery = 4. Try to use the binary backup (the datadir copy) on a test installation of the same version to see if it is machine related or data related.